# get Blank Response Subscription Status URL IAP from Apple server, Status Update Notifications, statusUpdateNotification

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Status Update Notifications, statusUpdateNotification

I set  Subscription Status URL in my APP in iTunes account like https://www.xxxxxx.xx/iospushnotification.php

I also successfully tested **nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://www.xxxxxx.xx/iospushnotification.php**

I also implemented php code in iospushnotification.php file to get JSON response

I purchased successfully Auto renewal Subscriptions Sandbox but I did not get any Status Update Notifications I get blank [] JSON response from apple server to my server.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6

Comment: 2 years later, I'm having this issue as well. I don't suppose you found a fix?

Comment: Hi @Ankur

Did you get the solution?

Comment: @Niraj Actually Php Developer got response only latest data

Comment: $data = array(
    'password'                  => $password,       // secret key on IAP server
    'receipt-data'              => $receipt_data,   // 'latest_receipt', base64 string
    'exclude-old-transactions'  => true
);

$post = json_encode( $data ) ;

$ch = curl_init() ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post ) ;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE ) ;

Comment: okay, thanks for replay, I will try with new apple account then It will works?

Comment: $return = curl_exec ( $ch ) ;
curl_close ( $ch ) ;

$result = json_decode( $return, true ) ;
switch ( $result[ 'status' ] ) {
    case 0 :
        return( 'Ok' ) ;
        break ;
    case 21006 :
        return( 'Expired' ) ;
        break ;
// etc.
}

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595499/trouble-receiving-notifications-from-itunes-connect-about-iap-status-change-even

Comment: @Niraj Please visit this link bro
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595499/trouble-receiving-notifications-from-itunes-connect-about-iap-status-change-even
or
merge above code in two comment you will get response

Comment: @AnkurPatel This code in nodeJS but I need php Code for that If you have then send me?

Answer (score 1):

if anyone still cares 2 years later, I found a solution, assuming you're using PHP.

from the stackoverflow post [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php) we need to do something like this:

```
$appleData = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

then `try` to `json_decode($appleData)` from there.

(I've never had to do something so weird to get POST data before, but I've mostly used frameworks before; unfortunately, I do not currently have that luxury...)